# Why can't pass Integer and string to Object parameters in Java method

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm new to Intellij IDEA and I wrote the following code but it cannot be compiled successfully (Integers and Strings can't be passed to the method with Object parameters). What is strange is that this code works in Eclipse with JDK1.8.

I really can't figure out where the problem is. Does it have something to do with the Intellij setting?

Error:

```
Error: (12, 18) java: incompatible type: int cannot be converted to java.lang.Object
```

Code:

```
public static void func(Object obj){
    System.out.print(obj.toString());
}
public static void main(String argv[]){
    func(3);
}
```

Comment: Paste the error message you get.

Comment: I use intellij too and copy/paste your code and everything is fine

Comment: Wild guess: You are _not_ using Java 8 here. Check your Project Settings, your project language level may be set to something ancient.

Comment: One of possibilities (but that would exclude case where you claim it works fine in Eclipse) could be that you created your own Object class (somewhere in your package or in other package but you imported it). In that case JDK could not see String or Integer as proper subclass of your Object.

Comment: Error: (12, 18) java: incompatible type: int cannot be converted to java.lang.Object

Comment: Strange. This should be handled by autoboxing which was introduced in Java 1.5. Are you sure you are using Java 8 here (or your project is not set to support only 1.4 or earlier version)?

Comment: Thank you Michael Piefel, it got solved

Comment: @BinbinLyu Could you post your solution as an answer so others with same problem could use it in the future?

Comment: Seriously what is off topic about this? The question contained enough information to reliably reproduce the problem, and find a solution. People were too quick with the trigger finger in this instance, perhaps... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go in to your Project Structure - ctrl + alt + shift + s

Go to `Project Settings` -> `Project`

Ensure `Project Language Level` is what you require (in your case, I think you need at *least* 5, but you might as well use 8).

Comment: I got it, Thank you

Comment: Was this the correct answer? It would help other people if you "accept" the answer (click the green tick icon)